# How to make pdf to open in viewer instead of downloading in mozila

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, embed

i am using jspdf library and the pdf opens in the modal viewer incase of chrome and edge, but it downloads the pdf and opens in mozila.
Can anyone help me out to sort out this issue, i want my application to work in same way in mozila as well.

Demo: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdzg6s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

IN html i have used:

```
<button class="pull-right" (click)="captureScreen()">PDF</button>
<div class="container" ></div>
<embed id="convertToPdf" type="application/pdf"  width="100%" Content-Disposition= "inline" height="100%" [ngStyle]="{display: (displayTable ? 'block' : 'none')}">
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your browser setting like this

1. open Mozila
2. click on browser setting icon
3. click on Option
4. after open option window scroll down and you see the Applications section , under this section you can see the PDF section change it to "SHOW PREVIEW IN FIREFOX"[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, in my firefox browser this was already set, even though it is happening like that